# JSon Array into HTML Select Option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, json

so I'm a real noob when it comes to javascript.
I tried all the solutions here on the site and I checked a few other things from google, but I didn't find anything that worked for me.

I have to create a json array and importat that into a select option list. The goal is to choose music titles from a listbox.

Here's my current html code (if you need more of the code tell me, for now I will just post what I think is necessary):

```
<td><input id="anzahl" type="number" min="1" max="100"></td>
<td><select id="mySelect" name="Titel">
<option id="01"></option>
<option id="02"></option>
<option id="03"></option>
<option id="04"></option>
<option id="05"></option>
<option id="06"></option>
<option id="07"></option>
<option id="08"></option>
<option id="09"></option>
<option id="10"></option>
</select></td>
...
```

EDIT: Here's the updated code, but it still doesnt work.

```
function initSelBox_Product() {
var titelliste= [
{"Produktid":"01","Titel":"Dangerous","Band":"David Guetta","Nettoeinzelpreis":"1.99"},      
{"Produktid":"02","Titel":"Sun goes down","Band":"Robin Schulz","Nettoeinzelpreis":"1.99"}, 
{"Produktid":"03","Titel":"Fade out lines","Band":"The Avener","Nettoeinzelpreis":"1.99"}, 
{"Produktid":"04","Titel":"Walk","Band":"Kwabs","Nettoeinzelpreis":"1.99"}, 
{"Produktid":"05","Titel":"Blame","Band":"Calvin Harris","Nettoeinzelpreis":"1.99"}, 
{"Produktid":"06","Titel":"Geronimo","Band":"Sheppard","Nettoeinzelpreis":"1.99"}, 
{"Produktid":"07","Titel":"Animals","Band":"Maroon 5","Nettoeinzelpreis":"1.99"}, 
{"Produktid":"08","Titel":"What are you waiting for?","Band":"Nickelback","Nettoeinzelpreis":"1.99"}, 
{"Produktid":"09","Titel":"Shake it off","Band":"Taylor Swift","Nettoeinzelpreis":"1.99"}, 
{"Produktid":"10","Titel":"Chandelier","Band":"Sia","Nettoeinzelpreis":"1.99"} ];


for (var i = 0; i < titelliste.length; i++) {
    var select = document.getElementById("mySelect");
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.text = titelliste[i].Titel;
    option.value = titelliste[i].Produktid;
    select.add(option);
}
```

}

Comment: Note: Use `JSON.parse(titelliste)` instead of `eval('(' + titelliste + ')')`.

Comment: You are doing `options[j].Text` and `options[j].Value`.  Have a look at your array.  The objects don't have those properties.

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work. But if I understand correctly you want me to replace options[j].Text with for example options[j].Titel right?

Comment: Yes.  You need to get the data from your object, however it's named :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things need changing in your code.

- You don't need to eval the JSON as long as you know it is valid you are OK.
- An `<option>` tag doesn't have a "text" attribute. In jQuery you should use `$('.selector').text()` to change the inner text for a tag
- Your JSON object has Titel and Produktid as properties, not text and value.
- Be careful ... your `<select>` tag has a different id attribute than the one you specify in `$('#mySelect').append(newOption);` (Your select is id="select" not "mySelect").

Here's a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4qhg882z/1/).

Comment: thanks i finally got it to work :D don't know what the problem was, i tried your solution earlier, it didnt work, but now it does. Thanks to everyone else who helped me aswell, learned a lot today :)

Answer (score 4):

Here's a pure JavaScript option:

```js
var titelliste = [
    { "Produktid": "01", "Titel": "Dangerous", "Band": "David Guetta", "Nettoeinzelpreis": "1.99" },
    { "Produktid": "02", "Titel": "Sun goes down", "Band": "Robin Schulz", "Nettoeinzelpreis": "1.99" },
    { "Produktid": "03", "Titel": "Fade out lines", "Band": "The Avener", "Nettoeinzelpreis": "1.99" },
    { "Produktid": "04", "Titel": "Walk", "Band": "Kwabs", "Nettoeinzelpreis": "1.99" },
    { "Produktid": "05", "Titel": "Blame", "Band": "Calvin Harris", "Nettoeinzelpreis": "1.99" },
    { "Produktid": "06", "Titel": "Geronimo", "Band": "Sheppard", "Nettoeinzelpreis": "1.99" },
    { "Produktid": "07", "Titel": "Animals", "Band": "Maroon 5", "Nettoeinzelpreis": "1.99" },
    { "Produktid": "08", "Titel": "What are you waiting for?", "Band": "Nickelback", "Nettoeinzelpreis": "1.99" },
    { "Produktid": "09", "Titel": "Shake it off", "Band": "Taylor Swift", "Nettoeinzelpreis": "1.99" },
    { "Produktid": "10", "Titel": "Chandelier", "Band": "Sia", "Nettoeinzelpreis": "1.99" }
];
for (var i = 0; i < titelliste.length; i++) {
    var select = document.getElementById("Select");
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.text = titelliste[i].Titel;
    option.value = titelliste[i].Produktid;
    select.add(option);
}
```

```html
<select id="Select" name="Titel"></select>
```

It is fairly obvious from your code that you're not familiar with how jQuery works, so I would recommend sticking with pure JavaScript until you get a full understanding of the language itself.

What I am doing here is very simple:

```
for (var i = 0; i < titelliste.length; i++) {
    var select = document.getElementById("Select");
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.text = titelliste[i].Titel;
    option.value = titelliste[i].Produktid;
    select.add(option);
}
```

First, I create a `for` loop to loop through each of the JSON objects contained in the `titelliste` array.

Then, at each iteration:

- I assign a variable to the `select` element.
- Create an `option` element
- Assign the `text` attribute of the option to the `Titel` value in the JSON object
- Assign the `value` attribute of the option to the `Produktid` value in the JSON object
- Add the newly created option to the `select` element

I hope this help you understand a little more about what's going on in the code.

Comment: Thanks, I tried your code, but it didn't work for me. Still no options in the select box on my site.

Comment: @Atiyo If you just copy/pasted my JavaScript code, it wouldn't work exactly with your HTML - I changed the ID of the select element from `select` to `Select`.  I prefer to have all of my ID's captialized.

Comment: Yes I checked it before I tried it and changed everything so it fits for my code. Still didn't work, I have the feeling sth is wrong with my pc/eclipse.

Comment: Does the code work if you run the snippet above?  If so, then there may be something else in your code somewhere that is throwing an error that would cause the remainder of your code to not execute.

Comment: Yes the code works if i run the snippet. Is it maybe a problem that the select options is in a table? Do i have to add maybe sth like .table in the js code?

Comment: Nope, it's accessing the `select` element directly by ID, it doesn't matter what the parent element is.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `map()`. The parameter `val` of the function is an object that contains `Produktid` and `Titel`. So you can use the `map()` function. Here's an example:

```js
var titelliste= [
        {"Produktid":"01","Titel":"Dangerous","Band":"David Guetta","Nettoeinzelpreis":"1.99"},
        {"Produktid":"02","Titel":"Sun goes down","Band":"Robin Schulz","Nettoeinzelpreis":"1.99"},
        {"Produktid":"03","Titel":"Fade out lines","Band":"The Avener","Nettoeinzelpreis":"1.99"},
        {"Produktid":"04","Titel":"Walk","Band":"Kwabs","Nettoeinzelpreis":"1.99"},
        {"Produktid":"05","Titel":"Blame","Band":"Calvin Harris","Nettoeinzelpreis":"1.99"},
        {"Produktid":"06","Titel":"Geronimo","Band":"Sheppard","Nettoeinzelpreis":"1.99"},
        {"Produktid":"07","Titel":"Animals","Band":"Maroon 5","Nettoeinzelpreis":"1.99"},
        {"Produktid":"08","Titel":"What are you waiting for?","Band":"Nickelback","Nettoeinzelpreis":"1.99"},
        {"Produktid":"09","Titel":"Shake it off","Band":"Taylor Swift","Nettoeinzelpreis":"1.99"},
        {"Produktid":"10","Titel":"Chandelier","Band":"Sia","Nettoeinzelpreis":"1.99"} ];
var options = titelliste.map(function(val, ind){
    return $("<option></option>").val(val.Produktid).html(val.Titel);
});
$('#mySelect').append(options);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="mySelect"></select>
```

**Reference:**

- [**map()**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/)

Also look at another iteration
 - [**each()**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)

Comment: Instead of appending strings like that, use proper functions to avoid issues with funky characters (like quotes within the text): `jQuery("<option></option>").val(val.Produktid).html(val.Titel)`

Comment: @MH2K9, <pendantic> you're using a `map()`, but in the style of the `each()` construct. Typically, a map 'translates' / returns items in an array or object into a new array of items, returning the resulting array from the call to `map()`. Currently, you're not returning items inside the `map()` function, but iteratively building the resulting string... a pattern more appropriate for an `each()`. </pedantic> I will edit your answer, as I really like you map-based solution (and it can be improved). It can be tested at https://jsfiddle.net/r28Ly010/.

Answer (score 0):

void main's answer is pretty clear and concise.

There is no need to use eval since the variable is already an array of objects.
Your select box should be empty considering you are going to append elements to it anyways.

Here is a jsfiddle still using a javascript for loop:

http://jsfiddle.net/horxu2yc/

```
<select id="mySelect"></select>
```

---

```
function initSelBox_Product() {
    var titelliste = [
    {"Produktid":"01","Titel":"Dangerous","Band":"David Guetta","Nettoeinzelpreis":"1.99"},      
    {"Produktid":"02","Titel":"Sun goes down","Band":"Robin Schulz","Nettoeinzelpreis":"1.99"}, 
    {"Produktid":"03","Titel":"Fade out lines","Band":"The Avener","Nettoeinzelpreis":"1.99"}, 
    {"Produktid":"04","Titel":"Walk","Band":"Kwabs","Nettoeinzelpreis":"1.99"}, 
    {"Produktid":"05","Titel":"Blame","Band":"Calvin Harris","Nettoeinzelpreis":"1.99"}, 
    {"Produktid":"06","Titel":"Geronimo","Band":"Sheppard","Nettoeinzelpreis":"1.99"}, 
    {"Produktid":"07","Titel":"Animals","Band":"Maroon 5","Nettoeinzelpreis":"1.99"}, 
    {"Produktid":"08","Titel":"What are you waiting for?","Band":"Nickelback","Nettoeinzelpreis":"1.99"}, 
    {"Produktid":"09","Titel":"Shake it off","Band":"Taylor Swift","Nettoeinzelpreis":"1.99"}, 
    {"Produktid":"10","Titel":"Chandelier","Band":"Sia","Nettoeinzelpreis":"1.99"} ];

    for (var key in titelliste)
    {
        var option = titelliste[key];
        var newOption = $('<option/>');

        newOption.val(option.Produktid);
        newOption.text(option.Titel);

        $('#mySelect').append(newOption);
    }

}

initSelBox_Product();
```